# Trying to return values on a registry subkey

Tags: c#, registry

I'm brand new to registry queries, so bear with my ignorance.

I'm having difficult time figuring out why the number of values coming back from .GetValueNames() does not match .ValueCount.  The ValueCount returns 7, but the list created by GetValueNames lists 25 values.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"..mypath");
        string[] nameList = regKey.GetSubKeyNames();
        string parentKey = "xxx";

        // Create a list of strings to put registry key values into
        List<string> oRegNameList = new List<string>();
        string[] oSubKeyList = new string[]{};

        if (nameList.Count() == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No registry key was found for that");
        }
        else
        {   
            foreach (string keyname in regKey.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                try
                {
                    using (RegistryKey key = regKey.OpenSubKey(keyname))
                    {
                        if (keyname.Contains(parentKey))
                           MessageBox.Show("Registry key found : " + key.Name + " contains " + key.ValueCount + " values");
                        {
                            oRegNameList.Add(key.Name);
                            oSubKeyList = key.GetValueNames();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Security.SecurityException)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        int keyVal = 1;
        foreach (string oSubKeyName in oSubKeyList)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Key " + keyVal + " = " + oSubKeyName);
            keyVal++;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not a debugging error? Like checking the count of oRegNameList.Count instead of oSubKeyList .Length? This is very unusual, and can mean a corrupted registry maybe.

Comment: No, I'm not sure of anything...   I wasn't even sure that I was counting the right  items, to be honest.  I was hoping that somebody would just tell me that I was making a silly tired eyes mistake...